# Is $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq C \to A\cup B \subseteq C$ valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

My proof is 
$C \cup A = C \cup B = C$

$(x \in A\cup B \to x \in C)$ $\Rightarrow (x \in A\cup B\cup C \to x \in C)$ $\Rightarrow (x \in C \to x \in C)$

so $(x \in A\cup B \to x \in C)$ is true.

Is that valid? I'm not sure about my solution.

Comment: That's like saying $1=-1\Rightarrow 1^2=(-1)^2,$ so $1=-1$ is true.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! but I can't understand it..

Comment: What @KentaS is pointing out is that your chain of implications ($\implies$) begins by assuming what you're supposed to be proving.

Comment: You are trying to prove $(x \in A\cup B \to x \in C)$ is true, but all you said was that $(x \in A\cup B \to x \in C)$ implies a true statement (i.e., $(x \in C \to x \in C)$).

Comment: Thank you! I undetstand it. I should have started with $x \in A \cup B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks fine, perhaps add $A\cup B\cup C=(A\cup C) \cup (B\cup C)$

I would write it as:

$x \in A\cup B \implies x \in A\lor x\in B \implies x \in C\lor x\in C\implies x \in C$

$\therefore A\cup B\subseteq C$

Comment: Thank you! I understand it!

Comment: Just to be a stickler, your last $\implies$ should really be a $\therefore$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $x\in A\cup B\to x\in C$, so that expression shouldn't be your premise, nor should you adopt notation that gives the impression it is. The clearest way to explain why the theorem is true is to subdivide $x\in A\cup B$ into two cases. The first, $x\in A$, implies $x\in C$ because $A\subseteq C$. The second, $x\in B$, works similarly.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it!